# Magento 2 Data Migration SQL error 'Column not found' Column in m2 DB but not in m1 DB

Tags: magento2, sql, migration, data-migration

im having this error:

[image]

Its the first data migration step, the integrity step. Anyone knows what to do with that?
Thanks!

Comment: which command you have run?

Comment: php bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml

Comment: php bin/magento -r migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.9/config.xml -a please try using this